# How Rotate image with css or javascript

Tags: javascript, css, rotation, image-rotation

I want to know if there is a way to rotate images without using fotoshop, i want to use css or javascript

The result that im looking for is [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/40931/how-can-you-convert-a-2d-image-into-a-rotating-3d-image-using-photoshop-cs5-exte)

The following solution works but i want to rotate my image without hover property , if i remove the hover here the image dont rotate

```
<style>

#card img:hover {
transform: rotateY(360deg);
-webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
transition-duration: 1.5s;
-webkit-transition-duration:1s;
}
</style>
```

if found the efect that i want here [here](http://thewebrocks.com/demos/3D-css-tester/)

Comment: `transform : rotate(DEGREE)`

Comment: [Go there if you want to chat about it](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107642/room-for-pdknight-and-guillermo-nahuel-varelli)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS' `rotate`, `rotateX`, `rotateY`, `rotateZ`. Little example:

```
img {
    transform: inherit;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    width: 100px;
}
img:hover {
    transform: rotateX(45deg)
                rotateY(45deg)
                rotateZ(45deg);
}
```

## [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ywsL9zrv/)

`rotate` is 2D transform method and `rotateX`, `rotateY`, `rotateZ` are 3D transform methods.

#### W3Schools references:

- [2D transforms](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp)
- [3D transforms](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_3dtransforms.asp)

Answer (score 1):

```
img {
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking like following code and Here is the fiddle [**Link**](https://jsfiddle.net/voco447o/) and [**Other Link**](https://jsfiddle.net/voco447o/2/)
This might help you!!

```
<img class="image" src="https://www.arxan.com/wp-content/uploads/assets1/images/demo.png" alt="" width="120" height="120">

<style>
.image {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    margin:-60px 0 0 -60px;
    -webkit-animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
    animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
}
@-moz-keyframes spin { 100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@-webkit-keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform:rotate(360deg); } }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this class :

```
var ImgRotator = {
angle: parseInt(45),
image: {},
src: "",
canvasID: "",
intervalMS: parseInt(500),
jump: parseInt(5),
start_action: function (canvasID, imgSrc, interval, jumgAngle) {
    ImgRotator.jump = jumgAngle;
    ImgRotator.intervalMS = interval;
    ImgRotator.canvasID = canvasID;
    ImgRotator.src = imgSrc;
    var image = new Image();
    var canvas = document.getElementById(ImgRotator.canvasID);
    image.onload = function () {
        ImgRotator.image = image;
        canvas.height = canvas.width = Math.sqrt(image.width * image.width + image.height * image.height);
        window.setInterval(ImgRotator.keepRotating, ImgRotator.intervalMS);
        //theApp.keepRotating();
    };
    image.src = ImgRotator.src;
},
keepRotating: function () {
    ImgRotator.angle += ImgRotator.jump;
    var canvas = document.getElementById(ImgRotator.canvasID);
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.save();
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
    ctx.rotate(ImgRotator.angle * Math.PI / 180);
    ctx.drawImage(ImgRotator.image, -ImgRotator.image.width / 2, -ImgRotator.image.height / 2);
    ctx.restore();
}
```

}

Usage :

```
ImgRotator.start_action(canvasID, image_url, intervalInMilliseconds, jumgAngle);
```

HTML (just provide a canvas where you want to rotate the image):

```
<canvas id="canva" width="350" height="350"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

Infact Using CSS and jquery we can do better, I mean rotate the whole body on load

```
function bodyRotate() {
        var angleX = 0, angleY = 0, angleZ = 0;
        var incX = -1, incY = -1, incZ = -1;
        var xStop = -180, yStop = -180, zStop = -180;
        var timerID =
        window.setInterval(function () {
            angleX += incX; angleY += incY; angleZ += incZ;
            var angle = "rotateX(_X_deg) rotateY(_Y_deg) rotateZ(_Z_deg)";
            angle = angle.replace("_X_", angleX).replace("_Y_", angleY).replace("_Z_", angleZ)
            $("body").css({ "transform": angle });
            if (angleX < xStop && angleY < yStop && angleZ < zStop) {
                incX *= -1; incY *= -1; incZ *= -1;
            }
            if (angleX > 0 && angleY > 0 && angleZ > 0) {
                window.clearInterval(timerID);
                $("body").css({ "transform": "rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg)" });
            }
        }, 10);
    }
    $(document).ready(bodyRotate);
```